# Laravel 5.4 Showing 404 Not Found (Public Storage)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question regarding to public storage and storage itself

After i done inserting the files to the storage.
then in the views page i want to display the files that i store to the storage.
but i got problem i got error.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

- I've run php artisan storage:link
- The image exists in the public storage folder

[Image Exist in the public storage folder & I've run the php artisan storage link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDLum.jpg)

**This is my code, how can i insert the file to storage.**

```
$filename =  $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
$request->file->storeAs('storage',$filename);
```

**This is my code, how to display the image to the view page**

```
@foreach($home_slider as $get_data_slider)
   @if($get_data_slider->slider_sorting == '1')
                
      <a href="{{$get_data_slider->link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{ asset('/public/storage/'.$get_data_slider->file.'') }}" class="d-block w-100"></a>
                
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I found out that i can't access the localhost:8000/public/storage/1.jpg

[404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmo4s.jpg)

But when i use the localhost:8000/storage/1.jpg the file is showing.
[Showing image when the url is without public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCWVH.jpg)

Thanks..

Comment: try changing the permissions of storage folder to 777?

Comment: how to change permission of storage? @j.albertoureña thanks

Comment: @DevGe instead of asset you should use {{ Storage::url($pr->$get_data_slider->file) }}

Comment: @SalmanZafar yes that storage::url laravel helper working however why this path is not working /public/storage/ and can't viewed to the browser

Comment: it is because you are just linking storage folder to public to make files and other stuff in the storage folder accessible.but in actual the real path of your file is storage/filename..

Comment: @SalmanZafar ah. thanks for the suggestion to me.

Comment: @SalmanZafar so everytime i need to retrieve files image to the database i need to use Storage::url helper of laravel?

Comment: if you are storing file on local storage then you should use Storage::url

Answer (score 7):

If you use Vagrant, `php artisan storage:link` should be run under Vagrant. Otherwise, folder mapping would be wrong and that's one of the reasons why do you get 404.
So, first run `vagrant ssh`, then find your project folder and run `php artisan storage:link`.

Comment: YESSSSSSS!!!!!! Thank you! Upvoted. I was running from  the local project folder.

Comment: thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu i have been in this error for 2 hours

Answer (score 6):

I had to run `php artisan storage:link` from the vagrant box to get the symlink to actually take effect.

Comment: How this solution is any different than mine, posted almost 1 year before this?

Answer (score 1):

instead of asset you should use:

```
{{ Storage::url($pr->$get_data_slider->file) }}
```

for more info visit [file System laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-urls)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the helper `asset()` , you are directly in the public folder. 
So your src should be

```
src="{{asset('storage/'.$get_data_slider->file.'')}}".
```

Everything that is accessible to users from the browser is in the public folder, and for that reason you don't need to put 'public' in the url anymore. That is why the first url (localhost:8000/public/storage/1.jpg) is not found while the second one (localhost:8000/storage/1.jpg) displays your image. 
When you use the first one, it's like you have another folder named public (which contains the storage folder) into your public folder.

Answer (score 0):

**asset()** - Generate a URL to an application asset.

**url()** - Generate a URL to an named route.

The asset() method is used to include CSS/JavaScript/images files, you can use it in this cases

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('use.typekit.net/zjb5wvv.js') }}"></script>
<img alt="logo" src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}">
```

The files must located in the **public** folder.

In your case :

```
<a href="{{$get_data_slider->link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$get_data_slider->file.'') }}" class="d-block w-100"></a>
```

**P.S** : No need to explicitly add public folder inside asset();